# Compute Number of Attributes efficiently in flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying to get the number of attributes a flink's `DataSet` has, the first attempt was simply:

```
dataset.input
    .map(_.vector.size)
    .reduce((_, b) => b)
    .collect
    .head
```

Then, looking at the implementation of [Solver](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-ml/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/ml/optimization/Solver.scala#L53) I saw it does it this way:

```
// TODO: Faster way to do this?
dataset.map(_.vector.size)
    .reduce((a, b) => b)
```

But the **TODO** comment says it all.

So, I came out with this implementation:

```
dataset.first(1)
    .map(_.vector.size)
    .reduce((_, b) => b)
    .collect
```

Is there a more efficient implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest would be

```
dataset
  // only forward first vector of each partition
  .mapPartition(in => if (in.hasNext) Seq(in.next) else Seq())
  // move all remaining vectors to a single partition, compute size of the first and forward it
  .mapPartition(in => if (in.hasNext) Seq(in.next.vector.size) else Seq()).setParallelism(1)
  .collect
```

Using `reduce` or `groupReduce` is less efficient because might move data to a single machine without reducing it first and results in on function call per input record. `mapPartition` is called once per partition and only forwards the first element of the input iterator.

Comment: Thank you very much!, You should open a PR to Solver.scala

Comment: Isn't it this equivalent? `dataset..mapPartition(in => if (in.hasNext) Seq(in.next.vector.size) else Seq()).setParallelism(1).collect`? I am receiving the same result.

Comment: The result is the same, but before reducing the data set, all records are shipped to a single partition. Hence, it adds network IO and should be slower for large DataSets.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks.